# Why are my props `undefined` when using redux and react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I tried to add a state to my application that just saved a boolean when some event has passed. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

**Reducer:**

```
import * as actionTypes from '../constants/action-types.js';

const initialState = [{
  eventPassed: false
}];

export default function eventPassed(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.EVENT_PASSED:
      return true;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Action:**

```
import * as actionTypes from '../constants/action-types';

export function eventPassed(eventPassed) {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.EVENT_PASSED,
    payload: { eventPassed: eventPassed }
  };
}
```

**Container around component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import Example from '../components/example.jsx';
import { eventPassed } from '../actions/app-actions';

class ExampleContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Example {...this.props} />
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators({
    eventPassed
  }, dispatch)
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  eventPassed: state.eventPassed
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ExampleContainer);
```

**Component:**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class Example extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.action = this.action.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.actions.eventPassed(true);
  }

  action() {
    console.log(this.props.eventPassed);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.action}>Action</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

When I try to log **"this.props.eventPassed"** in the **`<Example />`** component it gives me "**undefined**". Is there something missing? This seems to be the most simple use of the store in redux.

Comment: Your reducer must return the state object, in your case {eventPassed: true}

Comment: There is no this.props.eventPassed on the `<Example />` component.  See my answer below

Comment: Edited my answer to be more readable

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> ### Why is this.props.eventPassed logged as "undefined"?:
>
> The action function (`eventPassed`) you are trying to access at this point does not exist at **`this.props.actions.eventPassed`**.  It
>   actually exists solely on **`this.props.actions`**.
>
> This is because you bound the action method to the value '**actions**'
>   in your mapDispatchToProps.  This is turn provides gives access to the
>   `eventPassed` action via `this.props.actions`.
>
> Since this.props.actions points to `eventPassed`, by trying to access
>   `this.props.actions.eventPassed` you are trying to access the property
>   of 'eventPassed' on the action `eventPassed`.  The result is that when
>   you log for this property you receive "**undefined**"

---

#### Other necessary amendments:

**`mapDispatchToProps` needs to return a value**

An [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with a block body ***does not automatically return a value*** and therefore one must be defined.  So your function needs to look like:

```
mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return { actions: bindActionCreators(eventPassed, dispatch) }
}
```

---

**Initial state is an array containing an object:**

```
const initialState = [{
  eventPassed: false
}];
```

Since you're trying to reference it later as an `object { eventPassed: true}` and not an array of objects `[ { eventPassed: true } ]` it should be:

```
const initialState = {
  eventPassed: false
};
```

---

**The reducer needs to pass back the correct updated (but *unmutated*) state:**

```
export default function eventPassed(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.EVENT_PASSED:
      return {
        ...state,
        eventPassed: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

What you were initially doing was returning a state that was no longer an object (or in the original case an array of object) but just the value of `true`

Comment: Re-reading docs over and over again, re-watching tutorials, looking at other peoples code, days of sweat, and this post had the answer to my problem: "Initial state is an array containing an object", wish i could upvote this x100.

Comment: @jtlindsey: Glad you found it useful!

Comment: plus one for arrow functions, saves a lot of time

Comment: Just a minor correction it does return a value if you do it like in the example provided, it returns an object const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({ actions:  bindActionCreators(eventPassed, dispatch) });

Its the same as return { ...content }

Answer (score 2):

In your `reducer` you initialize your state with array of object has `eventPassed` property, meanwhile you return just the boolean and that's not correct because it replace the initial state, so the initState could be just an object holding the boolean, and you must return the state based on the `payload` sent with the action dispathed to be as follow:

```
import * as actionTypes from '../constants/action-types.js';

const initialState = {
  eventPassed: false
};

export default function eventPassed(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.EVENT_PASSED:
      return {
        ...state,
        eventPassed: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Also, in your `component` you may need to change:

`this.props.eventPassed` to `this.props.actions.eventPassed`

Comment: this.props.actions.eventPassed is not working, though followed same approach, maybe component is not correctly connected to store, by me.