# How is user.name rendering when user is undefined in React component? How to call action creators to ensure that user is defined?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jwt

I have a web application where users have to be authenticated and then the authenticated user is stored in application state.

The user authentication route assigns a JWT to the user.

When the user returns, the JWT is passed to the `findUser()` action. However, the user piece of state is still undefined when I transition to the protected route (the dashboard). However, when the dashboard loads, the user is known. The Dashboard uses the same `findUser()` action.

This image shows that the dashboard loads with the user name (bob) while the props are shown as undefined in the console.log in Developer Tools.

See - in partucular:

```
App renderMainContent props: 
{auth: {…}, user: undefined, monkeys: undefined, cupcakes: undefined, signoutUser: ƒ, …} <- is in App.js renderMainContent() 
bundle.js:59163 /api/user/finduser <- is in App.js renderMainContent() 
bundle.js:59565 I'm totally going to show auth <- is in App.js renderMainContent() 
bundle.js:59163 /api/user/finduser <- is in App.js renderMainContent() 
bundle.js:59546 App has this.props: <- is in App.js componentDidMount()
{auth: {…}, user: undefined, monkeys: undefined, cupcakes: undefined, signoutUser: ƒ, …} <- is in App.js componentDidMount()
bundle.js:59163 /api/user/finduser <- is in App.js componentDidMount()
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined <- is in UserDashboard.js
```

**the TypeError is because the Dashboard is trying to find the monkeys for the user, but the user is still undefined. What I don't understand is how the user name is rendered if the user is undefined.**

[image: screenshot of app with console]

I have tried many approaches, mostly layering on more findUsers, but I think this is the wrong way to go. Not only is it very un-DRY, it is not working and seems against the whole point of managing the state in the store.

A [similar problem posted on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635804/why-are-my-props-undefined-when-using-redux-and-react-js) was corrected by ensuring the new state is passed from the reducer. That does not appear to be my problem here.

Also, [similar undefined props problem did not check that the props existed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43201982/react-redux-can-view-props-in-browser-console-but-return-undefined-when-render), but I am checking for user, so it should not pass.

Still other SO questions have shown actions not being called, but my action is called, just not returning (fast enough???) I know that the findUser action works and returns the user which gets into the store through the FETCH_USER action.

**Here are my questions:**
1. How should I re-find a user when they load the app? (is the findUser action which eventually goes to my API and gets the user from the token a reasonable way to do that?
2. Should I have the props in app, wait for everything to return from the server and THEN load the dashboard with the user as props (like  or should I continue to just load  and `connect` the dashboard to the redux store?
3. How is the user name rendered "BOB" on the dashboard but the user is undefined?

**Thank you. I have included code here and a [link to the full project on github](https://github.com/monkeywithacupcake/mern-cupcake).**

**App** The main app.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {  HashRouter, Route, Switch  } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as actionCreators from '../actions';

import Header from './common/header';
import Footer from './common/footer';

// landing unauth
import Landing from './pages/landing';

// user auth
import UserDashboard from './user/userdashboard';
import Signin from './auth/signin';
import Signout from './auth/signout';
import Signup from './auth/signup';

// special pages
import About from './pages/about';

class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('App has this.props:', this.props);
        if (this.props.auth.authenticated) {
            if (!this.props.user) {this.props.findUser();}
        }
       // adding this here did not help
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        console.log('shouldComponentUpdate');
        return nextState !== this.state;
    }
    renderMainContent() {
        console.log('App renderMainContent props:', this.props);
        if (this.props.auth.authenticated) {
            if (!this.props.user) {this.props.findUser();}
            console.log("I'm totally going to show auth");
            return <UserDashboard />; // this.props.user is still undefined
        } else {
            return <Landing />;
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <HashRouter>
                <div className="main">
                    <Header />
                    <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
                    <Route exact path="/signin" component={Signin} />
                    <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
                    <Route exact path="/signout" component={Signout} />
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path="/"
                        component={() => this.renderMainContent()}
                    />
                    </Switch>
                    <Footer />
                </div>
            </HashRouter>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        auth: state.auth,
        user: state.user.user,
        monkeys: state.userData.monkeys,
        cupcakes: state.userData.cupcakes
        // state: state,
        // authenticated: state.auth.authenticated
    };
}

function mapDispachToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispachToProps)(App);
```

**UserDashboard** The authenticated/protected route where user is still undefined until it is called again in component did mount or finally gets the result here?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import * as actions from '../../actions';
//import subcomponents


class UserDashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //handle a bunch of bindings
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.user != undefined) {
            const userid = this.props.user.id;
            this.props.fetchUserMonkeys({ userid });
            this.props.fetchUserCupcakes({ userid });
        } else {
            try {
                await this.props.findUser();
                const userid = this.props.user.id;
                this.props.fetchUserMonkeys({ userid });
                this.props.fetchUserCupcakes({ userid });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    }

    // rendering a bunch of conditional stuff

    renderName() {
        if (this.props.user != undefined) {
            const name = this.props.user.name;
            return <h1>Hi, {name[0].toUpperCase() + name.substr(1)}</h1>;
        } else {
            console.log('trying to render Name but user is undefined');
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">

                <div className="section">
                    <div className="row valign-wrapper">
                        <div className="col m6 s12">{this.renderName()}</div>
                        <div className="col m6 s12 center">
                            <button
                                className="btn-large"
                                onClick={this.handleRefresh}
                            >
                                Refresh
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                {// this.render conditional stuff }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        auth: state.auth,
        user: state.user.user,
        monkeys: state.userData.monkeys,
        cupcakes: state.userData.cupcakes
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(UserDashboard);
```

**Reducers**

```
// /reducers/auth_reducer
import {
    AUTH_USER,
    UNAUTH_USER,
    AUTH_ERROR
} from '../actions/types';

export default function authReducer(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case AUTH_USER:
            return { ...state, error: '', authenticated: true};
        case UNAUTH_USER:
            return { ...state, authenticated: false };
        case AUTH_ERROR:
            return { ...state, error: action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

// /reducers/user_reducer
import {
    FETCH_USER
} from '../actions/types';

export default function authReducer(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                user: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

// /reducers/index
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'
import authReducer  from './auth_reducer';
import userDataReducer from './userdata_reducer';
import userReducer from './user_reducer'

export default combineReducers({
  form: formReducer,
  auth: authReducer,
  user: userReducer,
  userData: userDataReducer
});
```

**Find User Action** part of /actions/index

```
export function findUser() {
    return function(dispatch) {
        const url = `${USER_API_URL}/finduser`;

        console.log(url);
        const request = axios.get(url, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
            }
        });
        request
            .then(response => {
                console.log('findUser has RESPONSE', response.data.foundUser);
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_USER,
                    payload: response.data.foundUser
                });
            })
            // If request is bad...
            // -Show an error to the user
            .catch(() => {
                console.log('error');
            });
    };
}
```

I have this all in a [github repo](https://github.com/monkeywithacupcake/mern-cupcake). Currently, this issue is on the `master` branch, but it will remain on the poorly named `bootstrap` branch.